# Set Terminal tab name w/ AppleScript

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I have the following script, which opens Terminal, connects to a remote host and launches a script there:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "ssh me@myserver" 
    delay 10
    do script "sh ./startserver" in front window    
end tell
```

How can I set the name for this Terminal tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "ssh me@myserver" 
    delay 10
    do script "sh ./startserver" in front window 
    set input to "\"\\033]0;<your title here>\\007\""
    do script "echo -n -e " & input   
end tell
```

Replace `<your title here>` with whatever text you wish your title to be.

Comment: If I add `in front window` in last `do script` it works, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
tell app "Terminal" to set custom title of tab 1 of front window to "my tab name"
```

Comment: IMO, this is the better option from AppleScript.